# How to use charles in a system with proxy settings?

Tags: debugging, proxy, charles-proxy

I am using a virtual pc from my office, in which I want to test with charles.
That Windows OS uses a proxy for connecting to net.
In Charles software, When I **uncheck** the "enable windows proxy" checkbox, I am able to **connect** to the internet, but connections from localhost are not recorded!
When I **check** it, I get,

**Charles Error Report**

```
Name lookup failed for external proxy server
Charles failed to resolve the name of your external proxy server into an IP address.    
Check your external proxy configuration in the External Proxy Settings.
The actual exception reported was:
java.net.UnknownHostException: http://webproxy.****.***.*****.net<br>
```

Though I get this error, when "enable windows proxy" checkbox is checked I am able to record localhost requests!.
Why is this?
In External Proxy Settings, "use External proxy" is enabled, which when unchecked -internet works but not recording.
My aim is to capture all requests sent by softwares from OS other than a browser.
How to do it? pls help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your VPC is probably on a different subnet which allows bypass of the windows proxy -- which would also explain why it can't resolve the host name of the proxy (different subnet). Check your Network settings in the Virtual PC and see if you can't use a different method to connect to the network (NAT, bridged connection, etc).